# EntryModel attributeConfigs method throwing undefined index

Tags: entrymodel

I am attempting to read out the entry field attributes by using the attributeConfigs array of the [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EntryModel).

When I review the EntryModel object, using id and title as an example. I request the attribute configs like this:

```
    $entry->attributeConfigs['id'] // Works
    $entry->attributeConfigs['title'] // Undefined index error
```

All though the index exists in the array

```
    [_attributeConfigs:Craft\ContentModel:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [maxLength] => 11
                [min] => -2147483648
                [max] => 2147483647
                [decimals] => 0
                [type] => number
                [unsigned] => 
                [length] => 10
                [column] => integer
            )

        [title] => Array
            (
                [required] => 
                [maxLength] => 255
                [label] => Title
                [type] => string
            )
```

Is there any way I can access these configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An entry's `title` is stored on the [ContentModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ContentModel), so you'd need to do:

```
$content = $entry->getContent();
$content->attributeConfigs['title'];
```